# Xperia L (C2104) unusual behavior when GPS is active

Tags: gps, sony-xperia-l

Anyone with a Xperia L could help me confirm if this behavior is unusual? I just bought the phone (3 days) and noticed that, whenever the GPS is active, the wifi gets **very** unstable.

It goes like this: I connect to my Wifi, then open an application such as Google Maps. A few seconds later, the Wifi disconnects and the 3G data kicks in. Moments later, the phone identifies the wifi and reconnects.

Does anyone experience the same behavior? Is there a solution? I'm about to send it back to the store, but I want to make certain that this isn't a common issue or something I could solve myself.

UPDATE 1:

As requested, the Android version is 4.1.2.

Comment: Provide a logcat here, to aid trouble-shooting? And what version of Android as well?

Comment: @t0mm13b just added the Android version to the answer, I'm getting the log...

Comment: @t0mm13b oh, it seems one can't read the logs unless it's a root in jellybean... I won't root the phone so it doesn't void the warranty, is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upgrade to Android 4.2.** That fixed the problem to me and the original poster. I was getting an average of approximately 100 disconnections per day, in about three weeks. Since upgrade a few days ago, there were only 7 disconnections, even with *Google's location service* enabled. I think the firmware update 15.0.A.1.31 (based on Android 4.1.2) introduced the problem, but anyway we confirm that it is fixed in 15.3.A.0.26 (the upgrade to Android 4.2.2).

Comment: I will check the build number -- it's actually my girlfriends' phone. Do you think this is something specific to Brazilian versions? The issue is very apparent, I can't believe it passed QA testing. This weekend we where at a store and tested a phone on display and got the same behavior.

Comment: Renato, the firmware's 15.0.A.1.31.

Comment: Renato, Sony just upgraded the firmware to 15.3.A.0.26, and the problem seems solved! Can you test it at your end?